# ¿Cómo dividir el texto en un dropdown?

Tags: html, angularjs, bootstrap

estoy listando una serie de notificaciones en mi dropdown, quiero dividir cada una de estas, pero no sé como hacerlo. Intenté meter la etiqueta LI que tiene la clase divider dentro del ng-repeat pero no funciona. ¿Alguna solución?
Dejo la foto de como se ve.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Notificaciones">
                    <i class="fa fa-bell fa-fw" style="color: #138A8A"></i> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu alert-dropdown">
                    <li ng-repeat="datalist in Notificaciones">
                        {{ datalist.TEXTO_NOTIFICACION }}
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                </ul>
                <!-- /.dropdown-alerts -->
            </li>
```

Comment: ¿Existe algún separador entre los textos? Por ejemplo un salto de linea (`\n` o `<br />`)

Comment: No, intenté poner un hr pero queda con demasiado espacio. En la foto se listan dos mensajes distintos y lo que quiero es que estas queden separadas por la etiqueta que tengo abajo con la clase "dividers"

Comment: @RubxnMC no conozco mucho angularjs, pero por lo que entiendo `ng-repeat` repite solo la etiqueta marcada por lo tanto lo que haces no te funciona, lo mejor seria que pusieras la clase `divider` dentro  del `li` en otra etiqueta

Comment: @JuankGlezz Lo intenté pero sale error en la etiqueta "ul" igualmente no funciona. Puse la etiqueta angularjs para filtrar la pregunta bastante.

Comment: Hazlo con CSS, puedes darle más margen a los `li` o si quieres poner un separador usar un borde

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar creando una clase con `border-bottom`

```
li-class  {
border-bottom: solid;
border-color: #000;
border-width: 0.1px;
}
```

Tendrias algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya si quieres un mejor estilo puedes ya adicionarlo a la clase.

Comment: Gracias! me sirvió